# $post->ID not working but the get_the_id() is

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, page-template

I created a custom post type from a Plugin. Then in a function like `show_data()` I queried the post type along with its post meta data (Custom Fields). Then in Page Template I used the function to show the queried data. Within the loop I did something like:

```
while( $my_query->have_posts() ){
   $my_query->the_post();

   echo $post->ID;

   echo get_the_id();

   echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_field', true );

   echo get_the_title();

}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

I did not return anything but simply those `echo`s. And in my Page Template I used simply:

```
show_data();
```

Now the problem is: the loop is showing the Post Title (`get_the_title()`) and the post ID from `get_the_id()` only.

But the `$post->ID` is not showing the ID, so the post_meta is not showing too.

What can cause the problem?

Comment: [variable scope](http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: `var_dump($my_query);` -- Do you have posts? Look toward the end of the object dump.

Comment: Thank you all. Solved it from @TomJNowell's answer from the linked post. And thanks for your advises too. They're also valuable.